# Как оптимизировать ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

Добавил в ckeditor свои теги подскажите теперь как его оптимизировать? Либо как можно уже в оптимизированный добавить свои плагины теги?

Comment: А что вы подразумеваете под его оптимизацией?

Comment: Ну при создании редактора на странице ckeditor.com/builder  в самом низу есть big и optimized я выбрал big с ним проще работать добавил пару тегов и теперь не пойму как оптимизировать все это дело

Comment: Если теги добавили через плагины, то можно сразу было качать оптимизированный вариант. Если нет, то делайте добавление через плагины и качайте оптимизированный вариант. Потому что в оптимизированном варианте все файлы js сжаты, а весь функционал ядра собран в один файл. В сырцах же нет сжатия и функционал разбросан по куче отдельных js.

Comment: В плагинах нет нужных мне тегов, как быть? Может есть возможность в оптимизированный добавить свои плагины, там же есть плагины у меня подобные, вот только где их подключить непойму

Comment: Сами оптимизируйте. Думаю ничем от оптимизации обычного js оптимизация ckedit-а не отличается.

Comment: Да там скрипт не такой большой, вопрос как его подключить в big версии они подключаются через config.js а в оптимизированной как то подругому

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Качаете оптимизированный вариант CKEditor и ставите на сайт;
2. Создаете свой плагин с новыми тегами и копируете его в папку плагинов установленного CKEditor;
3. Инициализируете CKEditor на страницах (я делаю это перед тегом `</body>`):

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ваш.сайт/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   CKEDITOR.replace( "ckeditor1" , {
       extraPlugins: "имяВашегоПлагина1,имяВашегоПлагина2", // <-- подключение ваших плагинов
       toolbarGroups: [ // <-- настройки кнопок
           { name: "basicstyles", groups: [ "basicstyles", "cleanup" ] },
           { name: "paragraph", groups: [ "list", "indent", "blocks", "align", "bidi", "paragraph" ] },
           { name: "links", groups: [ "links" ] },
           { name: "insert", groups: [ "insert" ] },
           "/",
           { name: "styles", groups: [ "styles" ] },
           { name: "colors", groups: [ "colors" ] },
           { name: "clipboard", groups: [ "clipboard", "undo" ] },
           { name: "document", groups: [ "mode" ] }
       ],
       removeButtons: "Save,NewPage,Preview,Print,Templates,Find,Replace,BidiLtr,BidiRtl,Language,Flash,PageBreak,Iframe"
   } );
   </script>
   ```

По примеру:
Содержимое CKEditor лежит на сайте в папке `js/ckeditor/`;
Ваши плагины лежат в папках `js/ckeditor/plugins/имяВашегоПлагина1/`, `js/ckeditor/plugins/имяВашегоПлагина2/`;
`ckeditor1` id textarea на которую "вешается" CKEditor.

Comment: Благодарю уважаемый! Попробую через пару часов!

Comment: Добавил скрипт до закрытия /body выдает ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEditor' of undefined(…)  
 a @ ckeditor.js:332
CKEDITOR.replace @ ckeditor.js:336
(anonymous function) @ (index):712    <--- CKEDITOR.replace( "ckeditor"

Comment: @AdminCommunity, вы id textarea указали правильно в CKEDITOR.replace()?

Comment: Если указываю id textarea куда привязан выводит ошибку... ckeditor.js:332 Uncaught The editor instance "topic_text" is already attached to the provided element. Уже привязан ну как бы логично, а как он может быть не привязан?

Comment: В общем эти ошибки есть, но плагин добавился... в панель и работает, непойму чего шибки тогда...

Comment: @AdminCommunity, у вас у textarea класс `ckeditor` прописан? Если да, то уберите. Вот пример CKEDITOR.replace() из документации http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_installation-section-adding-ckeditor-to-your-page но без параметров настройки.

Comment: class не прописан, там другие классы к эдитору не относятся... + некоторые теги не работают... походу из за ошибки этой...

Comment: @AdminCommunity, оставьте вызов в таком виде `CKEDITOR.replace( "id textarea" , {extraPlugins: "имяВашегоПлагина"});`, а то видимо вы его скопировали как я написал в ответе (у меня настройки для full варианта).

Comment: В общем нашел где этот id еще раз закреплялся, ошибки убрал, но блин почему-то некоторые плагины отказались работать... и ошибок нет в логе пусто... только серая надпись зависла... Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEditor' of undefined(…) Та не то я всё поправил и кстате, плагины нужно писать через,безпробелов, а то ругается, будто не существует такого.

Comment: Ладно я еще сегодня покручу это дело, ПРИ-МНОГО БЛАГОДАРЕН ВАМ за ПОМОЩЬ! Простите + дать не могу репутации не хватает...

Comment: @AdminCommunity, про пробел думал уже, но глянул в код, а там регулярка вида `/\s*,\s*/g`. Должна сама пробелы удалять возле запятых :)